# On the relationship between $\Re\operatorname{Li}_n(1+i)$ and $\operatorname{Li}_n(1/2)$ when $n\ge5$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, summation, polylogarithm

**Motivation**
$\newcommand{Li}{\operatorname{Li}}$
It is already known that:
$$\Re\Li_2(1+i)=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$$
$$\Re\Li_3(1+i)=\frac{\pi^2\ln2}{32}+\frac{35}{64}\zeta(3)$$

And by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290798/a-conjectured-value-for-operatornamere-operatornameli-4-1-i), assuming $\Li(1/2)$ is a simpler form than $\Re\Li(1+i)$, we are able to simplify $\Re\Li_4(1+i)$.
$$\Re\Li_4(1+i)=-\frac5{16} \Li_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{97 \pi ^4}{9216}-\frac{5}{384} \ln^42+\frac{1}{48} \pi ^2 \ln^22$$

Going further, I tried to find some numerical evidence to simpify $\Re\Li_5(1+i)$, and I conjectured that

> $$\Re\Li_5(1+i)\stackrel?=\frac{5}{32} \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{2139 \zeta (5)}{4096}-\frac{1}{768} \ln^52+\frac{1}{288} \pi ^2 \ln^32+\frac{97 \pi ^4 \ln2}{18432}$$

As I verified it up to 1000 digits, I believe it holds. How can we prove it?
**Thoughts**
Well, I honestly does not have much thoughts on it but I think turning it into an integral or Euler sum is a possible pathway. Therefore, I turned it into an integral: $$\int_0^1\frac{54x^2-150x+59}{2x^3-6x^2+5x-2}\ln^4xdx\stackrel?=\ln^52-\frac83\pi^2\ln^32-\frac{97}{24}\pi^4\ln2-\frac{6417}{16}\zeta(5)$$
**Further Question**
Can $\Re\Li_n(1+i)$ be simplified? Or at least can it be turned into a combination of $\Li(1/2)$ and some other simpler constants? (Assuming Multiple Zeta Values are simpler)

**Update**
Another numerical experiment suggests $$\Re\operatorname{Li}_6(1+i)\stackrel?=-\frac{5 \text{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{64}+\frac{69 S}{512}+\frac{207 \zeta (3)^2}{4096}+\frac{2139 \zeta (5) \log (2)}{8192}+\frac{18779 \pi ^6}{30965760}-\frac{\log ^6(2)}{9216}+\frac{\pi ^2 \log ^4(2)}{2304}+\frac{97 \pi ^4 \log ^2(2)}{73728},$$where $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_n}{n^5}$.

Further numerical experiments suggest that $$J_n=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1-x}{x^2-2 x+2}+\frac{5 x}{x^2-2}\right) \ln^nxdx$$ may be turned into the same form of the result of "logarithm integral", mentioned in the paper in the comment, containing $1−x,x,x+1$ only, of weight $n+1$. If we can find a substitution that can directly convert it into "log integral", the whole question will be solved by evaluating this integral.
**Another Update**
An interesting phenomenon discovered by observing the coefficient between adjacent terms:
$$J_{n-1}=\frac4n\left(\frac{\ln2}2\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^na_kP_k(n)$$
where $$P_k(n)=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-(k-1))(4\ln2)^{-k}$$
and
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline k&0&1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline a_k&-1&0&5\zeta(2)&0&-343\zeta(4)&4278\zeta(5)&8832S+3312\zeta^2(3)-53383\zeta(6)\\\hline\end{array}$$
Therefore, it may be true that all $a_k$ is a linear combination of alternating multiple zeta function with integer coefficients of weight $k$. **(i)**
Also, there might be a formula to calculate $a_k$ directly. **(ii)**
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline k&7\\\hline a_k&-304707\zeta(7)-2208(7\zeta(3)\zeta(4)+6\zeta(2)\zeta(5)+16\zeta(-5,1,1)+8\zeta(-4,2,1))\\\hline k&8\\\hline a_k&\frac1{51}\left(-\frac{199260125\zeta(8)}{144}+280600\zeta(3)\zeta(5)-261088\zeta(-7,1)-34827\zeta(6,2)+2944(3\zeta^2(3)\zeta(2)+7\zeta(-3,3,2)+4\zeta(-3,3,1,1))\right)\\\hline\end{array}$$
This supports the conjecture (i). (Note that $S$ can also be regarded as Multiple Zeta Value.)

Comment: Great question (+1)

Comment: Can you even briefly elaborate on how you managed to conjecture that?

Comment: @stokes-line I used Mathematica's `FindIntegerNullVector` function to test if there is possibility to connect $\Re\operatorname{Li}_5(1+i)$ with $\operatorname{Li}_5(1/2)$. Then, I got coefficient that might be right. Finally, I run the numerical test of the equality.

Comment: @Displayname I used command `N[Re[PolyLog[5, 1 + I]] - 5/32 PolyLog[5, 1/2] - 2139/4096 Zeta[5] +  Log[2]^5/768 - \[Pi]^2 Log[2]^3/288 - 97/18432 \[Pi]^4 Log[2], 1000]` with Mathematica version 10.0.1.0. The output is $0.\times10^{-1049}$.

Answer (score 4):

lets try to find it by Lerch Zeta function , firstly we have
$$Re\left(\text{Li}_n(1+i)\right)=Re\left(\text{Li}_n(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}})\right) $$
to use series we need $|x|<1$ So by using the identity of polylogarithm
$$ \text{Li}_n(z)+(-1)^n\text{Li}_n\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=-2\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \eta(2k)\frac{\ln^{n-2k}(-z)}{(n-2k)!}, n\in N/\text{{1}} $$
So
$$ \text{Li}_n(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}})=(-1)^{n+1}\text{Li}_n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{\frac{-\pi i}{4}}\right)-2\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \eta(2k) \frac{\ln^{n-2k}(-1-i)}{(n-2k)!} $$
now lets trying with new polylogarithm function which we can use its series :
$$ Re\left(\text{Li}_n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{\frac{-\pi i}{4}}\right) \right)=Re\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\left( \sqrt{2} e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}} \right)^{-k}}{k^n}\right) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-\frac{k}{2}}}{k^n}  cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{4}\right)$$
now using double summation which known as:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} f(nk-p)=\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(nk-p)$$
therefore putting n=4
$$ Re\left(\text{Li}_n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{\frac{-\pi i}{4}}\right) \right)=\sum_{p=0}^3 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-\frac{4k-p}{2}}}{(4k-p)^n}  cos\left(\frac{\pi (4k-p)}{4}\right) $$
the cosine function can be simplify
$$cos\left(\frac{\pi (4k-p)}{4}\right)=cos\left(\pi k-\frac{\pi p}{4}\right)=(-1)^kcos\left(\frac{\pi p}{4}\right) $$
So,
$$ Re\left(\text{Li}_n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{\frac{-\pi i}{4}}\right) \right)=\sum_{p=0}^3 2^{\frac{p}{2}}cos\left(\frac{\pi p}{4}\right) \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-4)^{-k}}{(4k-p)^n}$$
then using Lerch Zeta function we get
$$Re\left(\text{Li}_n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{\frac{-\pi i}{4}}\right) \right)=-4^{-n-1}\sum_{p=0}^3 2^{\frac{p}{2}}cos\left(\frac{\pi p}{4}\right)\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},n,1-\frac{p}{4}\right)  $$
$$ =\frac{1}{4^{n+1}} \left(4 \text{Li}_n \left(\frac{-1}{4} \right)-\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},n,\frac{3}{4}\right)+2\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},n,\frac{1}{4}\right)  \right)$$
finally we have now for $n=2,3,4,5,...$
$$ \boxed{Re\left(\text{Li}_n(1+i)\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^{n+1}\left(4 \text{Li}_n \left(\frac{-1}{4} \right)-\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},n,\frac{3}{4}\right)+2\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},n,\frac{1}{4}\right)  \right)-\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \frac{2\eta(2k)}{(n-2k)!}Re\left[\ln^{n-2k}(-1-i)\right]}$$
to get it simply lets use $J_n$,$A_n$ and $B_n$
$$ Re\left(\text{Li}_n(1+i)\right)=J_n=\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^{n+1}A_n-B_n$$
where $B_n$ is defined by
$$ B_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \frac{2\eta(2k)}{(n-2k)!}Re\left[\left(\frac{\ln2}{2}-\frac{3\pi}{4}i\right)^{n-2k}\right] $$
So
$$ B_2=\frac{\ln^2{2}}{8}-\frac{11\pi^2}{96} ,\quad B_3=\frac{\ln^3{2}}{48}-\frac{11 \pi^2}{192} \ln2 ,\quad B_4=-\frac{1313}{92160}\pi^4+\frac{\ln^42}{384}-\frac{11\pi^2}{768} \ln^22 $$
$$ B_5=\frac{\ln^52}{3840}-\frac{11\pi^2}{4608}\ln^32-\frac{1313\pi^4}{184320}\ln2 \quad , B_6=-\frac{90941\pi^6}{61931520}-\frac{1313\pi^4\ln^22}{737280}-\frac{11\pi^2\ln^42}{36864}+\frac{\ln^62}{46080}$$
And
$$ A_n=4 \text{Li}_n \left(\frac{-1}{4} \right)-\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},n,\frac{3}{4}\right)+2\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},n,\frac{1}{4}\right) $$
which has an integral representation
$$ A_n=\frac{(-4)^{n+1}}{(n-1)!} \int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^2+1} \left(\ln(1-x) \right)^{n-1}dx$$
from your results for $J_2$ , $J_3$ and $J_4$ we can see :
$$ A_2=\frac{10\pi^2}{3}-8\ln^22 , \quad A_3=140\zeta(3)+\frac{16}{3}\ln^32-\frac{20\pi^2}{3} \ln2 $$
$$ A_4=320 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{343}{90}\pi^4+\frac{32}{3}\ln^42-\frac{20\pi^2}{3}\ln^22 $$
and we have now for $J_5$ and $J_6$
$$J_5=\frac{1}{4096} \left(4\text{Li}_5 \left(\frac{-1}{4} \right)-\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},5,\frac{3}{4}\right)+2\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},5,\frac{1}{4}\right) \right)-\frac{\ln^52}{3840}+\frac{11\pi^2}{4608}\ln^32+\frac{1313\pi^4}{184320}\ln2$$
$$J_6=\frac{-1}{16384} \left(4\text{Li}_6 \left(\frac{-1}{4} \right)-\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},6,\frac{3}{4}\right)+2\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},6,\frac{1}{4}\right) \right)+\frac{90941\pi^6}{61931520}+\frac{1313\pi^4\ln^22}{737280}+\frac{11\pi^2\ln^42}{36864}-\frac{\ln^62}{46080}$$

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064802/polylog-property-operatornameli-n1-i-1n-operatornameli-n-frac1i2?noredirect=1