# how to find closed form for $\int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^2+1} \left(\ln(1-x) \right)^{n-1}dx$?

Tags: integration, logarithms, closed-form, polylogarithm

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447529/on-the-relationship-between-re-operatornameli-n1i-and-operatornameli/4776340#4776340) in my answer I got real part for [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function)  at $1+i$ for natural $n$

$$ \Re\left(\text{Li}_n(1+i)\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^{n+1}A_n-B_n $$

where
$$ B_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \frac{2\eta(2k)}{(n-2k)!}\operatorname{Re}\left[\left(\frac{\ln2}{2}-\frac{3\pi}{4}i\right)^{n-2k}\right] $$
which is easy to evaluate the closed form by using [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) .

but for $A_n$ which defined
$$ A_n=4 \text{Li}_n \left(\frac{-1}{4} \right)-\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},n,\frac{3}{4}\right)+2\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},n,\frac{1}{4}\right) $$
by using [Lerch zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function) So it has an integral representation
$$ A_n=\frac{(-4)^{n+1}}{(n-1)!} \int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^2+1} \left(\ln(1-x) \right)^{n-1}dx$$
I got closed form for $n=2,3,4$ where
$$ A_2=\frac{10\pi^2}{3}-8\ln^22 , \quad A_3=140\zeta(3)+\frac{16}{3}\ln^32-\frac{20\pi^2}{3} \ln2 $$
$$ A_4=320 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{343}{90}\pi^4+\frac{32}{3}\ln^42-\frac{20\pi^2}{3}\ln^22 $$
my **Question** is how to find closed form for $A_n$ for natural $n$ ?

this question asked on [math over flow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464174/how-to-find-closed-form-for-int-01-fracxx21-left-ln1-x-rightn) .

Comment: I think Feynman trick on $\log(1-ax)$ results in a mess of partial fractions but *could* be solvable every time